# Why doesn’t two ways of calculating stationary distribution result in the same answer?

Tags: r, monte-carlo, transition-matrix

I use

```
matpow=function(M,n){
ans=M 
for(i in 1:(n-1)){
ans=ans%*%M
}
ans
}
```

to set the matpow function.
then I enter the transition matrix

```
M2=matrix(c(0.1,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.2,0.4,0,0.4,0,0.3,0.5,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0),nrow=4,byrow=T)
>M2  
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
[1,]  0.1  0.3  0.4  0.2 
[2,]  0.2  0.4  0.0  0.4 
[3,]  0.0  0.3  0.5  0.2 
[4,]  0.5  0.3  0.2  0.0
```

Then I use the matpow function to find the stationary probability distribution
to get the output:

```
> c(0,0,1,0)%*%matpow(M2,50)
      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] 
[1,] 0.1975309 0.3333333 0.2469136 0.2222222
```

This is where it stabilizes.
However when I use the package “castor” and use the command get_stationary_distribtution(M2), I don’t get the same result:

```
> print(get_stationary_distribution(M2)) 
[1] 0.4827586 0.2758621 0.0000000 0.2413793
```

I know they should equal, as I did use these two methods on another transition matrix and they were equal.
What is the problem here?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it have to do with the ergodicity of the transition matrix? Should I check that first? Could it be that it is periodic therefore doesn’t have a stationary distribution?

Comment: Start by explaining to us what `get_stationary_distribution` does.  According to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/castor/versions/1.5.7/topics/get_stationary_distribution), it's not relevant to this problem.